# Uniform scaling on array of point around average point c++

Tags: c++, matrix

What I am trying to do:

**1. scale uniformly an array of points around a point.
2. A point has to be an average point of array of points.**

The code below, seems to work, but I do not know if it is the proper way of doing that.

I know that uniform scaling is simply multiplying points by some value, but this is scaling on 0,0,0 point, how to do it around mean point?

The code could be subdivided by following steps:

1. Get the average point of the array of points, by summing up all positions and dividing by a number of points.
2. Ratio is scaling value
3. Then I do vector subtraction to get a vector pointing from point to average point.
4. I normalize that vector (I get unit vector)
5. Then I add that normalized vector to current point multiplied by (1 - ratio)*0.5

This last bit 5th point came totally from checking total length of the value.

All examples I came up before was using matrices in math, and I really not capable of reading matrix operations.

Is it the correct uniform scaling method, if it's not could you point out what I am doing wrong?

```
    //Get center of a curve 
    //That is average of all points


    MatMxN curveCenter = MatMxN::Zero(2, 1); //This is just 1 vector/point with x and y coordinates

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        curveCenter += points.col(i);

    curveCenter /= n;

    //Scaling value
    float ratio = 1.3;

   //Get vector pointing to center  and move by ratio
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        MatMxN vector = curveCenter - points.col(i);
        MatMxN unit = vector.normalized();
        points.col(i) += unit*(1 - ratio)*0.5; //points.col(i) this is point in array
    }
```

Comment: Uniform scaling a point in space is a semilinear transformation. You need only to multiply all the component of the point in space for the same scaling factor. If you want also to center the origin of the reference frame in the center of mass of the cloud of points then you average along the coordinates. It is semilinear because after scaling the metric (modulus for example) on the vector is changed (by the scaling factor): `points.col(i) *= ratio` is all you need.

Comment: I think you need to define what point will be the center of scaling. Center of the bounding box? Center of mass? Bottom left corner of bounding box? One of the points?

Comment: Your description is unclear, so nobody has any help of working out if your approach achieves.  Point 2:  what ratio?  What are you intending to scale?    Point 3:  what vectors are you subtracting?   What do you mean by "total length of the value"?    Generally speaking, uniform scaling requires selecting a centre of some sort and adjusting other points relative to it.    Your description does not convey anything like that to me.

Comment: Sorry, I will update the description. But what I want to do is to scale uniformly around a average point of array of points.

Comment: @Galik Yes it is what I am trying to do. First I want to get average point/or center point of bounding box and scale all the points around it.

Comment: @MatteoRagni I tried your option and it works well. But this i scaling on 0,0,0 point, how to do this on on arbitrary point in space?

Comment: @Peter Point2: I am scaling by custom ration let say 1.3. I am intending to scale polyline, which is essentially array of points. Point3: I imagined I could subtract average point of all points, from current point in polyline

Comment: @Petras - try to describe your intent in your question without requiring other people to guess what your imagining.

Comment: 4 and 5 make no sense. Why normalize? What happens if your vector happens to be zero? What if the ratio happens to be 1? Just multiply it by the ratio, then add back the point you subtracted in step 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to scale points using a specific center point (other than **0**), follow these steps:

1. Substract center from point `MatMxN vector = points.col(i) - curveCenter;`
2. Multiply vector by scaling factor `vector *= ratio`
3. Add center to the scaled vector to get new point `points.col(i) = vector + curveCenter`

This approach can be resolved to something remotely similar to your formula. Lets call the center `C`, the point to be scaled `P0`, the scaled point `P1` and the scaling factor `s`. The above 3 steps can be written as:

```
v0 = P0 - C
v1 = s * v0
P1 = v1 + C
```

=>

```
P1 = s * P0 + C * (1 - s)
```

Now we define `P1 = P0 + x` for some `x`:

```
P0 + x = s * P0 + C * (1 - s)
```

=>

```
x = s * P0 + C * (1 - s) - P0
  = C * (1 - s) - P0 * (1 - s)
  = (C - P0) * (1 - s)
```

So the update could be written as follows instead of using the 3 steps mentioned:

```
MatMxN vector = curveCenter - points.col(i);
points.col(i) += vector * (1 - ratio);
```

However, I prefer to write the substractions in reverse, because it is closer to the original steps and easier to understand by intuition:

```
MatMxN vector = points.col(i) - curveCenter;
points.col(i) += vector * (ratio - 1);
```

I don't know where you found the normalize and `*0.5` ideas.